# Python traceback issue regarding Popen

Tags: python

I'm getting this error when running my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./autoConnect.py", line 22, in <module>
    call("wicd-cli -yn " + str(defNum) + " -c")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 470, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Problem is. I don't know what it's telling me. I realize the below code is messy. It needs to be cleaned up. But for some reason python's tripping up here. Can someone tell me what's happening?

Thanks again,
Dragos

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import time
cmd = './checkOnline.sh'
while True:
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    if "0" in p.stdout.read():
        print time.ctime() + ": Offline"
        print "Attempting to reconnect..."
        print "Determining network profile..."
        cmdTwo = "wicd-cli -ySl | sed -n '2 p' | grep -i paws -c"
        pTwo = Popen(cmdTwo, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
        if "1" in pTwo.stdout.read():
            print "Network profile is \"1\""
            defNum = 1
        else:
            print "Network profile is \"2\""
            defNum = 2
        print "Connecting to network..."
        p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
        while "0" in p.stdout.read():
            call("wicd-cli -yn " + str(defNum) + " -c")
            p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
            time.sleep(3)
            if "0" in p.stdout.read():
                print "Failed to connect. Trying again..."
        print "Success, connected to network!"
    else:
        print time.ctime() + ": Online"
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` makes me wonder if you've specified the correct path to the file.

Comment: I feel so stupid.

call("wicd-cli -yn " + str(defNum) + " -c")

is the original code. It's not the right syntax... Command comes first, then it's arguments in an array, like so:
call(["ls", "-l"])

Comment: @dragos240: please include your answer as an answer and mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

Is wicd-cli -yn in your path?

You get this error if the command is not available.